# Why doesn't the dot command work after pasting in visual mode?

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

#### 1. Why doesn't this work?

If my text file is:

```
aaa
test bbbb test
test bbbb test
test bbbb test
```

I can yank `aaa`, select `bbbb` in visual mode, and type `"0p`, to replace it with `aaa`, with the idea of doing more replacements after (Or since vim 9.0, `P` has a similar effect).

Now if I place my cursor at the start of the next `bbbb`, and press `.`, `bbbb` is deleted. Why doesn't it paste `aaa`?

#### 2. Is there a way to make it work?

I know that from visual mode, instead of `"0p`, I could do `c<c-r>0<esc>` to paste in insert mode, but I would rather not have to enter insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember a put in visual mode ever being repeatable with `.`. I guess not enough people complained about it.

Recording a macro *before* doing the first put would be one workaround (assuming the cursor is on `aaa`):

```
yiw    " yank current word
ww     " move cursor to target
qq     " start recording in register q
viw    " visually select current word
P      " put over visual selection
q      " stop recording
j      " move cursor to next target
@q     " replay macro from register q
```

but it may require a bit too much forward thinking, IMO.

See `:help q`.

Here is a quick and dirty custom operator that kills two birds with one stone:

- is repeatable with .
- follows the operator+motion model, like `y` or `d`

The snippet:

```
function! Put(type, ...)
    normal `[v`]P
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <key> :set opfunc=Put<CR>g@
```

In your use case, you would use it like this (assuming the cursor is on `aaa`):

```
yiw        " yank current word
ww         " move cursor to target
<key>iw    " put over current word
j          " move cursor to next target
.          " repeat
```

See `:help :map-operator`.

Note that the operator+motion model is amazing when there is a motion that suits your needs but falling back to visual mode is very helpful when there is no fitting motion. If that's the case, then I am afraid the suggested solution will be of no use.

Maybe you should open a feature request?